# Centering text in emacs window is unresponsive

Tags: window, frames

On this site i found a very nice snippet of code to center a textblock of fixed width in my frame https://stackoverflow.com/a/23731757/4310112

The idea is that whenever the window size is change, the margins of the window are adjusted in a way that the text block keeps a pre defined fixed size. (The code is below.)

However it does not exactly what i expected. When i resize the window the text width changes as well. The will be some margins but not of the size intended. If i switch to another buffer and back the margins change to the correct size.

Something similar happens when i execute some command, for example `C-c C-c` in AucTex or just `M-x C-g`. Then all margins vanish and the text occupies the whole frame width. Again, switching buffers will restore the intended frame width.

```
;;Add left and right margins, when file is markdown or text.
(defun center-window (window) ""
  (let* ((current-extension (file-name-extension (or (buffer-file-name) "foo.unknown")))
         (max-text-width 80)
         (margin (max 0 (/ (- (window-width window) max-text-width) 2))))
    (if (and (not (string= current-extension "md"))
             (not (string= current-extension "tex")))
        ;; Do nothing if this isn't an .md or .tex file.
        ()
  (set-window-margins window margin margin))))

;; Adjust margins of all windows.
(defun center-windows () ""
  (walk-windows (lambda (window) (center-window window)) nil 1))

;; Listen to window changes.
(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'center-windows)
```

Comment: It would probably be better to start by asking, in a comment, for clarification from the [author of the code on the original S.O. site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349847/centering-text-in-emacs-window/23731757#23731757) than to start a new question thread here.

Comment: this was my first idea as well but commenting on answers needs 50rep

Comment: @user11712 Added comment for you at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23731757/1219634

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try `centered-window-mode`: https://github.com/anler/centered-window-mode

It centers the text of the window when there’s only one window in the frame. To enable it in all my LaTeX buffers I added the following hook

`(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'centered-window-mode)`